# Scala Nested Object Serialization

Tags: scala, serialization

Hi I have a case class A which contains variables pointing to another class B (with companion object, which has variables pointing to yet another class C which also has companion object). class B and C are from other libraries. What is the easier way that I could serialize my case class A?

```
case class A() {
  val b = B
}

//B & C are defined in a library that I have no control of
object B {
  val c = C
} 

class B{
  ...
}

object C{
  ...
}  

class C{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these classes are already `Serializable`, you don't need to do anything special, so the rest of the answer assumes they aren't.

If these fields can be reconstructed from others, mark them as `@transient` and implement `readObject` (as described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to restore them. Unfortunately, you can't initialize `val`s in `readObject` and will have to write something like

```
case class A() {
  private var _b = B
  def b = _b
}
```

If they can't, you need to store something they *can* be restored from in `writeObject` as well.

Finally, you can use one of the third-party serialization libraries like [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) or [Scala Pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling), because basically all of them allow to add support for types not under your control (otherwise they couldn't work with the types in standard Java library!)

Comment: Thanks. This is quite helpful! I looked at Scala Pickling before but didn't read into its code (it seems to lack docs and more examples). With a second deeper look on it, I tested and it worked.